# CircleCI 2.0: Build directory for scp / rsync deployment

Tags: php, build, continuous-integration, circleci

Re: CircleCI 2.0: Build directory for scp deployment

I’m confused as to the source folder to use for deploying to another server over SSH (scp, rsync, etc). I’ve tried the working_directory from my build, I’ve tried ~/repo_name and several other variations but without any luck.

I am just attempting to build the circleci-demo-php-laravel demo as a test.

https://github.com/dmgig/circleci-demo-php-laravel/blob/circleci-2.0/.circleci/config.yml

Thanks for any help.

Here’s the deploy step I’m hung up on. I've tried about everything - setting the working_directory in the build and deploy, using the `CIRCLE_WORKING_DIRECTORY` env variable that is created when the deploy machine spins up. I'm at a total loss.

```
run:
name: Deploy Over SSH
command: scp -r {WHAT_IS_THE_BUILD_DIR} serveradmin%mydomain.org@mydomain.org:~/domains/circleci.mydomain.org/html/
```

**UPDATE**

Though I did figure out a solution below buy combining the deploy under the build, I'm still confused by the relationship between build and deploy when they are under separate jobs. If anyone can clarify that, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was had wrong, which I figured out about 5 minutes after posting the bounty, was a difference in my `build` and `deploy` steps.

**Wrong**

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.1-node-browsers
...

  deploy:
    machine:
      enabled: true
```

**Correct**

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.1-node-browsers
...

  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.1-node-browsers
```

**FINAL** What I ended up with for a super simple, build and deploy over rsync is the following.

I actually removed the "workflow" with separate build and deploy sections entirely - it wasn't useful for me. I could do everything under the build step.

This is a very basic set up which just checks out a repo, installs composer requirements, and then transfers everything to a third-party server (in my case, MediaTemple) over rsync.

The only other step was to create and install an SSH key into the CircleCI project (there are many tutorials for this online).

```
# PHP CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.1-node-browsers
    working_directory: ~/beta
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: php composer.phar install
      - run: pwd
      - deploy:
          name: Deploy Over SSH
          command: rsync -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -arvc --exclude .git ~/beta/ myuser@mysite.org:~/domains/mysite.org/html/beta
```